# DateRangePicker color scheme in flutter

Tags: flutter, datepicker, daterangepicker

I would like the customize the DateRangePicker in flutter to look like the DatePicker.
I am using material 3:

screenshot of DatePicker:
[image]

screenshot of DateRangePicker:
[image]

Basically in the DateRangePicker you can barely see your selection. I want the background to be as dark as in the DatePicker.
A look at the source code of DateRangePicker reveals that it uses a app bar. I suspect this is the cause of the light color in the header background. But I don't know change that.

This is my code to show the date range picker:

```
                                 await showDateRangePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                    lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                                   );
```

I manage to achieve what I want thanks to the help of @Rohan Jariwala.
This is what works for me:

```
    await showDateRangePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                    lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                                    builder: (context, child) {
                                      return Theme(
                                        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                                          appBarTheme: Theme.of(context)
                                              .appBarTheme
                                              .copyWith(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Theme.of(context)
                                                        .colorScheme
                                                        .primary,
                                              ),
                                        ),
                                        child: child!,
                                      );
                                    });
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I just update my post with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add builder in `showDateRangePicker` in following way

```
builder: (context, Widget? child) => Theme(
            data: themeData.copyWith(
                appBarTheme: themeData.appBarTheme.copyWith(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    iconTheme: themeData.appBarTheme.iconTheme!.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  primary: Colors.red
                )),
            child: child!,
          ));
```

I've added colours to the appBar and colorScheme. You can change those colours.